# Moving to a sub-array in PHP, based on a value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to move array items into a sub-array based on a value, so for example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [Desc] => 'Sub category'
        [SubID] => null
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [Desc] => 'Listed item 1'
        [SubID] => 1
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [Desc] => 'Listed item 2'
        [SubID] => 1
    )
    [3] => Array
    (
        [Desc] => 'Item with no sub category'
        [SubID] => null
    )
)
```

Would become:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [Desc] => 'Sub category'
        [SubID] => null
        [SubSections] => Array
            (
                [Desc] => 'Listed item 1'
                [SubID] => 1
            )
            [2] => Array
            (
                [Desc] => 'Listed item 2'
                [SubID] => 1
            )
    )
    [3] => Array
    (
        [Desc] => 'Item with no sub category'
        [SubID] => null
    )
)
```

Sorry to be vague, I'm unsure of the best way of describing it, but hopefully the example above makes sense.

Thanks!

Comment: How does `SubID` relate to the array - because in your example a `SubID` of 1 matches the category at position [0] .... if that makes sense !

Comment: I concluded this from your example. You are assigning both 1 and 2 index elements to the 0 element. Thats my login. 2 and 3 goes to 0, both have SubID 1 -> 1 goes to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?
foreach($arr as $index=>$subArr){
  if($subArr['SubID']){
    $arr[$subArr['SubID']-1]['SubSections'][] = $subArr;
    unset($arr[$index]);
  }
}
?>
```

I think that this will do the work. Maybe some lite modification will be implied to

Comment: This shouldn't work if you have order of elements: `2: Parent node 4; 4: Parent node null`

Answer (score 2):

So, my solution probably isn't the prettiest, but it's based on an assumption that a category may appear after a child within the array, thus we figure out the categories first... then do another loop to populate sub categories.

```
$arr = Array (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [Desc] => 'Sub category'
        [SubID] => null
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [Desc] => 'Listed item 1'
        [SubID] => 1
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [Desc] => 'Listed item 2'
        [SubID] => 1
    )
    [3] => Array
    (
        [Desc] => 'Item with no sub category'
        [SubID] => null
    ) ) 

$new_arr = array();

// sort out the categories first foreach ($arr as $key => $item) {

foreach ($arr as $key => $item) {

    if (is_null($item['SubID']))
    {

        $new_arr[$key] = array(
            'Desc' => $item['Desc'],
            'SubID' => null
        );

        unset($arr[$key]);

    }

}

foreach ($arr as $key => $item) {

    $new_arr[$key]['SubSections'][] = array(
        'Desc' => $item['Desc'],
        'SubID' => $item['SubID'] - 1
    );

}
```

Comment: You're pretty close but there are a few mistakes here and there. First of all, you made a typo in the second `foreach` loop. Where it should be `$item['SubID']` you wrote `$itemP...`. Also, still in the second `foreach` loop, the variable `$key` in the `$new_arr[$key]` part should be `$item['SubID'] - 1` instead. Lastly, it might be a good idea to unset the elements from the array in the first loop right after you make a copy of it in the new array. That way in the second `foreach` loop you won't be checking an element that is a category, and thus eliminating the need to do the `if` statement.

Comment: You raise some good points Kermal, I've edited accordingly :-)

Answer (score 2):

I've little cropped your example :), in array `[0] => title, [1] => parent`

```
<?php

$arr = array(
    1 => array( '1', 2),
    2 => array( '2', 0),
    3 => array( '3', 1),
    4 => array( '4', 1),
);

$result = array();

foreach( $arr as $key => &$item){
    // Root element
    if( $item[1] == 0){
        $result[] = &$item;
        continue;
    }

    // Any other element
    if( !isset( $arr[ $item[1]])){
        die( 'Missing index');
    }

    // Initialize new child elements or append to existing list
    if( !isset( $arr[ $item[1]][2])){
        $arr[ $item[1]][2] = array( &$item);
    } else {
        $arr[ $item[1]][2][] = &$item;
    }
}

print_r( $result);
```

**Warning:** original array will be changed.

*Note: I'm using 0 as root index, not null... Realized that after implemented an example.*

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
<?php
 $array = array(
                array('desc'=>'Sub Category 1','subid' => null),
                array('desc' => 'list item 1','subid' => 1),
                array('desc' => 'list item 2','subid' => 1),
                array('desc'=>'Sub Category 2','subid' => null)
            );


    foreach ($array as $key => $val){
     if ($val['subid']){
      $sub_array = $val;
      if (is_array($array[$val['subid']-1]['subsections'])){
        $array[$val['subid']-1]['subsections'][] = $val;
      }else{
        $array[$val['subid']-1]['subsections'] = array($val);
      }
      unset($array[$key]);
     }
    }
    print_r($array);
?>
```